# Why does my Kenmore gas oven stop and relight itself?

Tags: oven

My oven will light, then stop and relight. The igniter glows during the process.
It did get to temp yesterday when using however it kept stopping and relighting. What could be the cause?

Comment: Never seen a door safety switch on a gas-fired... but maybe?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a dirty flame sensor. It probably just needs to be cleaned. Use steel wool and after cleaning don't touch with your fingers. It will get dirty again faster. If that doesn't work, the sensor is probably bad. Look up the model number for your Kenmore and order a new one. For cleaning and replacement there should be Youtube videos available.

Answer (score 1):

This *could* be a sign of a cracked igniter - at least for the last gas stove I used, the stove logic was that if the igniter was drawing current **X** it was hot enough to ensure ignition so the gas valve would open. As with almost all electric-ignitor gas ovens I've met, it ran the ignitor all the time the oven was calling for heat.

When it went bad, the crack reduced the current drawn below whatever **X** was, and gas would stop. Heating and cooling affected the contact of the crack, so it spent a while lighting erratically before it reached an end-point of not lighting at all. The igniter could be seen to glow, (so we thought it was fine) but an experienced tech suggested replacing it, and the old one was visibly cracked (and the new one glowed much brighter by comparison.)

As far as I recall, that stove did not have a separate flame sensor as such.

Comment: How does it knows the Flame is on without flame sensor ?

Comment: Never cleaned nor replaced a flame sensor in a stove. But I have replaced *working* igniters  (*not* visibly cracked) and solved problems, +1. I think on some igniters there's an integral FS.